# Ordering dictionaries by keylist

Tags: python, dictionary

I've tried looking this question up but i never seem to be able to find an answer that works the way i want it to.

the code so far is as follows:

```
dictionary = {}
list = ["this", "is", "my", "list"]
definitions = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dictionary = dict(zip(list,definitions))
print dictionary
```

the output is given as:

```
{'this': 1, 'list': 4, 'is': 2, 'my': 3}
```

i need the output to be in the form

```
{'this': 1, 'is': 2, 'my': 3', list': 4}
```

The list cannot be sorted alphabetically or numerically as the actual values I want to put in are somewhat randomized. it is crucial that the order is ordered by the order of the key in its list form.

I've tried using the method bellow however that still returns the same answer

```
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

If dictionaries are not the best way of doing this I am more than interested of learning a better way

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you _need_ the output to be that way? The whole point of a dictionary is to retrieve the items by key, so the orders in which the keys are stored internally (or displayed when you print the dictionary) are not relevant.

Comment: Dictionaries do not care about order. New key values added could be shown at first or at last, this is not a fixed thing about dictionaries.

Comment: Dictionaries don't have the concept of ordering. `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}` is the same as `{'b': 2, 'a': 1}`

Comment: Thanks Ashish Kasturia, I realise now that I had it in my head that the order mattered as it does in a list. thanks for that, looking back it was a bit of a silly question!

Answer (score 2):

You need to build your `OrdereDict` using the original order, and *not use the built-in `dict` at all*:

```
keys = ["this", "is", "my", "list"]
definitions = [1, 2, 3, 4]
OrderedDict(zip(keys, definitions))
```

The built-in `dict` type has no set order, it is an unordered type. Sorting applies *alphabetical ordering* to the keys, not your original order.

I've used the name `keys` instead of `list` here to not mask the built-in type.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> keys = ["this", "is", "my", "list"]
>>> definitions = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> OrderedDict(zip(keys, definitions))
OrderedDict([('this', 1), ('is', 2), ('my', 3), ('list', 4)])
```

If all you cared about is that your keys and values are paired up correctly, *that already happened*. `zip()` paired up your keys and values in the original order, *then* a dictionary was created from those pairings. It doesn't then matter what order the `dict` displays keys and values, the pairings are not going to be mixed up.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you put the data straight into the `OrderedDict`?

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> data = ["this", "is", "my", "list"] # don't use list as a variable name
>>> d = OrderedDict(zip(data, range(1, 5)))
>>> d
OrderedDict([('this', 1), ('is', 2), ('my', 3), ('list', 4)])
```

Note that your current attempt sorts the keys from the vanilla dictionary *alphabetically*, although you could do:

```
>>> d2 = dict(zip(data, range(1, 5)))
>>> d2
{'this': 1, 'list': 4, 'is': 2, 'my': 3}
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d2.items(), key=lambda t: data.index(t[0])))
OrderedDict([('this', 1), ('is', 2), ('my', 3), ('list', 4)])
```

i.e. use the `index` within the `data` list as the `key` for `sorted`.

Comment: just tried the first method and returned the same result however as someone pointed out in a comment to my question. the order itself doesn't matter as long as the key is paired with the correct data. i was treating a dictionary as if it were a list, when the whole point in a dictionary is to be referenced via the key. apologies for such a silly question!

Comment: @Sam: `zip()` took care of pairing up your values with your keys already. You can just stick with `dict()` if you don't care about the resulting order.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do that way :

```
import pandas as pd
list = ["this", "is", "my", "list"]
definitions = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df = pd.DataFrame({'definitions':definitions}, index=list)
```

Here what df looks like :

```
    key  values
0  this       1
2    is       2
1    my       3
3  list       4
```

And :

`df.to_json()` gives :

```
'{"definitions":{"this":1,"is":2,"my":3,"list":4}}'
```

As it's been said in the comments, it may not be the better way. But it's an option !

Comment: Uhm, no, the DataFrame will use the keys *in the order the dictionary produced them*. And if you got the desired order from the code you posted, then you got *very lucky*.

Comment: df.sort('values') sorts (in ascending order) the dataframe according to the column 'values'. What is lucky here ?

Comment: Ah, I misread your initial list and didn't see that the `my` and `is` keys are swapped. The OP *doesn't want to sort by value*. They want the original `list` order instead, so `'this', 'is', 'my', 'list'`.

Comment: Ok. So using a DataFrame may be better than dictionnaries. (And initialize with lists)

Comment: I am not sure if a dataframe is a better choice here. There is way too little info on the context to make that call. OrderedDicts have the advantage that they come with Python, for example.